# What format does this SQL need to be in for Oracle to accept it?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, oracle, quotes

I tried all of the following, in turn:

1) // as it was in the legacy code

```
ocmd.CommandText = "SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE,''DD'') "VALUE" FROM DUAL";
```

2) // adding a @

```
ocmd.CommandText = @"SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE,''DD'') "VALUE" FROM DUAL";
```

3) // try single quotes

```
ocmd.CommandText = "SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE,''DD'') 'VALUE' FROM DUAL";
```

4) // try two single quotes, like DD

```
ocmd.CommandText = "SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE,''DD'') ''VALUE'' FROM DUAL";
```

5) // try the @

```
ocmd.CommandText = @"SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE,''DD'') ''VALUE'' FROM DUAL";
```

1 and 2 gave me the compile-time error: "; expected" (on the "VALUE")

3, 4, and 5 gave me, "Message=ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"

Comment: Well, I'm not an Oracle expert, but I'd guess: "SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE,''DD'') ""VALUE"" FROM DUAL"; based on your error messages.

Comment: @MarkByers, i have removed the answer as you have presented yours. But that VALUE as is reserved should be in ". But im not 100% that it will fail on parsing.

Comment: @Vash: OK, I think you are right. It seems that it parses correctly. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/369

Comment: @MarkByers, nevertheless the key words should be avoided or passed with "". BTW nice page (sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: I still get "; expected" when doubling up on the value quotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following query will work in Oracle: [(sqlfiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/371)

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DD') "VALUE" FROM DUAL
```

However to write a double-quote inside a regular string literal in C# you need to escape it with a backslash:

```
ocmd.CommandText = "SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DD') \"VALUE\" FROM DUAL";
```

If you would rather use a verbatim string literal for whatever reason, then you need to escape a double-quote with another double-quote:

```
ocmd.CommandText = @"SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DD') ""VALUE"" FROM DUAL";
```

<sub>Note: As Vash pointed out in a comment, the double-quotes surrounding `VALUE` aren't actually necessary for Oracle to parse the query correctly.</sub>

Comment: Yep, these both work; thanks! Without strings, dates, and floats, programming would be a lot easier! ;-)